# svn:mergeinfo is not being cherry-picked properly between branches

Tags: svn, cherry-pick, svn-merge

I created a *^sandbox/feature-branch* from *^trunk* as a staging area to do a proof of concept.

But I don't want to reintegrate merge the feature branch back into *^trunk* because of the **sandbox** in its name.

I'd like to create a *^branches/feature-branch* and cherry-pick the changes one by one from the *^sandbox/feature-branch*.

And then reintegrate merge the nicer named *^branches/feature-branch* down into *^trunk*.

In testing I can acquire the change set easily but the **svn:mergeinfo** is not what I expect.  It does not include svn:mergeinfo entries added with the *^sandbox/feature-branch* commits.

## Creation Scenario

Working Copy: *^sandbox/feature-branch*

cherry pick code from *^branches/another-feature-branch*

This gives a commit with the changes and adds an **svn:mergeinfo** entry like this:
/branches/another-feature-branch:1234

## Cherry Pick Scenario

Working Copy: *^branches/feature-branch*

cherry pick code from *^sandbox/feature-branch*

This takes the change but the **svn:mergeinfo** change is not what I expect:
/sandbox/feature-branch:2345

But there is no mention that the change originally came from *^branches/another-feature-branch:1234*

Is there any way to get the original merge path included when cherry-picking commits in subversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your expectations: mergeinfo **always** reflect **only** P2P-exchange of data on merge between source and target of this operation and doesn't handle ancestors of source commit

> Is there any way to get the original merge path included when cherry-picking commits in subversion?

No (internally), and it isn't needed really. But you can edit mergeinfo by hand, if you want to have such additional useless bells&whistles

Comment: What happens if I try to merge ^branches/other-feature-branch into ^branches/feature-branch?  Doesn't the mergeinfo about the prior merge need to be there for the commit to be skipped?

Comment: @MichaelO'Cleirigh - no, **doesn't need** (only *can be, if...*). SVN-history isn't DAG, SVN for calculating final "their" state will use this (already indirectly merged) revisions, but already merged pieces of files will bethe same on "mine" and "their". I.e currently used "dumb" logic require repeated operations (collecting sources), but produce correct sources for merge. You suggested to have additional complex logic (take into account parents-of-parents-of on merge), skip additional revisions *and* generate **bad** final "their" source: just model it!!!